# How to turn a list within a dictionary into a dictionary within a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary which looks like this.

> {'Block': 
>   [{0: {'John', 'name'}, 1: {'123', 'weight'}, 2: {'New York', 'city'}}, {0: {'Mark', 'name'}, 1: {'245', 'weight'}, 2: {'Boston', 'city'}}]}

I'm trying to turn the list within it to another dictionary, so that it looks like this :

> {'Block': 
>   {{0: {'John', 'name'}, 1: {'123', 'weight'}, 2: {'New York', 'city'}}, {0: {'Mark', 'name'}, 1: {'245', 'weight'}, 2: {'Boston', 'city'}}}}

What is the cleanest way to do this? I keep getting erros saying that list indices must be integers or slices. Thanks

Comment: Can you post some example code you tried?  Right now the output you're trying to produce has a {} pair that isn't a dictionary (no key:value)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved this way, although I don't know if it's the cleanest way (I'll keep investigating):

```
a = {'Block': [{0: {'John', 'name'}, 1: {'123', 'weight'}, 2: {'New York', 'city'}},
           {0: {'Mark', 'name'}, 1: {'245', 'weight'}, 2: {'Boston', 'city'}}]}
for index,elem in enumerate(a):
   if a.get(elem):
      for x in a.get(elem):
          a[elem] = x
   else:
       a[elem] = {}


print(a)
```